# How can I declare window.Promise when I have proper Promise declaration?

Tags: typescript

I have downloaded Promise type declaration for TypeScript from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/es6-promises/es6-promises.d.ts), and I now properly have the declaration of Promise. Now I have to access window.Promise to check Promise support from the browsers. I cannot do that, because window.Promise property is not declared here, while Promise is. Thus, I tried to declare it by myself:

```
interface Window {
    Promise: typeof Promise;
}
```

Now, there is a problem. The "Promise" in *typeof Promise* actually refers Window.Promise, not Promise declaration, **so the type of Promise is now <any>, which I don't want.**

How can I properly declare window.Promise here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot do that, because window.Promise property is not declared here, while Promise is

You can check for `Promise` on `window` using :

```
if(window['Promise'] === undefined){
    // no support
}
```

> The "Promise" in typeof Promise actually refers Window.Promise, not Promise declaration

You need to access the global scope definition from the local scope. And TypeScript goes to the local scope, you are probably looking for something like this (notice temp variable foo):

```
declare module Promise{export var mem:number;}

var foo:typeof Promise;
interface Window {
    Promise: typeof foo;
}

window.Promise.mem = 123; // okay
```

Comment: I would be more happy if TS automatically defines window.Promise if we have Promise definition. Some functions including window.setImmediate is defined globally but not defined in Window interface, which is global. Anyway I should follow your suggestion at this moment. Thank you :)

Comment: @KagamiSaschaRosylight does update fix it for you? ... see : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/es6-promises/es6-promises.d.ts#L135-L141

Comment: Great, it works well! However, the type of foo should be *typeof Promise*, as TS requires type arguments in generic types (DefinitelyTyped type definition declares Promise as generic type), and simple Promise<any> won't work here. Thank you very much :)